# Datatables adding JSON data to footer <tfoot>

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I am using datatables to display some data in JSON format and I've included the query totals at the bottom of the JSON like so:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "provider_num": "381301",
            "provider_name": "COTTAGE GROVE COMMUNITY HOSPITAL",
            "261_total_bad_debts": "$0",
            "271_medicare_bad_debts": "$79,275",
            "281_non_medicare_bad_debts": "$-79,275",
            "1_cost_to_charge_ratio": "0.703459",
            "291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts": "$-55,767"
        }
    ],
    "total_bad_debts": 0,
    "total_medicare_bad_debts": 79275,
    "total_non_medicare_bad_debts": -79275,
    "total_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts": -55767
}
```

I'm a bit confused on how I can add them to the footer of my table as before I had access to the php variables directy and now I'm encoding them in the JSON. If anyone has any experience with this and using `footerCallback` in the datatables initialization that would really be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do use data from JSON response in DataTables footer as shown below.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
   'ajax': 'data/arrays.txt',
   'footerCallback': function( tfoot, data, start, end, display ) {    
      var response = this.api().ajax.json();
      if(response){
         var $td = $(tfoot).find('td');
         $td.eq(0).html(response['total_bad_debts']);
         $td.eq(1).html(response['total_medicare_bad_debts']);
         $td.eq(2).html(response['total_non_medicare_bad_debts']);
         $td.eq(3).html(response['total_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts']);
      }
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
       'ajax': 'data/arrays.txt',
       'footerCallback': function( row, data, start, end, display ) {    

            var api = this.api();
            var response = this.api().ajax.json();
            if (response) {

                $(api.column(3).footer()).html(
                    response.total_bad_debts
                );

                $(api.column(4).footer()).html(
                    response.total_medicare_bad_debts
                );

                $(api.column(5).footer()).html(
                    response.total_non_medicare_bad_debts
                );

                $(api.column(6).footer()).html(
                    response.total_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts
                );
            }
        } 
    });
```